# Why did a new BiqQuery connection retrieve data from GA4 only for the last few days even though older data is available?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I connected GA4 with BiqQuery and data set includes events only for the dates afterwards the project creation. Dataset like this is useless for me, I need data from the day when GA4 property was created. What is causing this limitation? I am using SandBox for now.